# Android : Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, sms

I am new to android and trying to fetch sms conversation for a specific number using the code shown below. This code results in a bunch of errors.

Can any one help me how to fix this issues?

```
String add = "address="+"'"+number+"'";
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
        String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,projection ,add,null,"date desc");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int index_Address = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");  
                int index_Person = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");  
                int index_Body = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
```

Logcat

```
04-02 13:21:14.912: E/CursorWindow(836): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 16 rows, 16 columns.
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.second/com.example.second.CInfo}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.second.CInfo.fetchConversations(CInfo.java:96)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.example.second.CInfo.onCreate(CInfo.java:54)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    04-02 13:21:14.922: E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
```

Comment: This error mostly comes when query is wrongly written. Make sure that field names of the database match with those you've written in query.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but when i use uri = content://mms-sms/conversations insted of content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true and run in emulator it works fine but when i use this code on my mobile it give me the error above.

Comment: Yes you are right Dhaval i got the issue thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the column you are trying to display data from exists in the cursor returned by the content provider.

If it try to access a column that doesn't exist, this exception is usually thrown. So check the projection/selection you passed to the content resolver in this case:

For example in a typical onCreateLoader method:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader running...");

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_ID,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_ICON,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_NAME,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_LONGITUDE,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_LATITUDE,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_ADDRESS,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_PHONE,
            OutletsContentProvider.KEY_OUTLET_EMAIL             
    };

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, OutletsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection,null,null, null);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader complete");

    return loader;
}
```

The cusorloader constructor expects you to pass in a string array of columns in the cursor to be returned. If i try to access say column OutletsContentProvider.KEY_I_DONT_EXIST, this exception will be thrown.

I hope this helps. :)